# Dropping elements into a dynatree

Tags: drag-and-drop, dynatree

I am just starting out with dynatree (which is indeed v. cool), but I have a non-standard use for it: sorting terms from a long list into the hierarchical Dynatree. Specifically, I want to drag-and-drop from outside the Dynatree onto a Dynatree element--preferably exploiting Dynatree's spring-loaded folders rather than expecting the user to manually open the relevant categories beforehand.

Could I get some specific guidance on how to achieve my dreams?

Thanks,
Steve Upstill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of he drag'n'drop samples seems to implement your use case:
You can drag the 'Drag me around' box over the right tree.

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-dnd3.html

The box is a simple query.draggable. 
The tree receives the standard events (onDragEnter, onDragOver, onDrop, onDragLeave).
Make sure to enable the `autoExpandMS` option.

Hope this helps
Martin

Comment: Martin,Sorry for the delayed response but I just got back to this problem. I did as you suggest and all is hunky-dory. NB: I couldn't figure out how to get dynaTree to take a drop from a non-dynaTree node (I thought I could manage with a callback), but I worked around it by turning my source into another dynaTree!